# Error Running ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

Using IE9 (9.0.8112.16421) I receive the following error in the debugger while running the script I'm working on:

> "Unable to get value of the property 'toLowerCase': object is null or
>   undefined"

in the following function:

```
function ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(func, depScriptFileName)
{ULSxSy:;
    depScriptFileName=depScriptFileName.toLowerCase();
    var eventName="sp.scriptloaded-"+depScriptFileName;
    return ExecuteOrDelayUntilEventNotified(func, eventName);
}
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: How do you use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`? Or if this error appears when trying to use it with oob sharepont file (`ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){...}, "sp.js")` for example)?

Comment: Second scenario exactly. I'm just calling it in a $(document).ready(ExecuteOrDelayScriptLoaded(function(){...}, "sp.js")); call. The embedded function works fine when I add it to a click event for a dummy button. So I know there is no issue in that.

Comment: Just to add some info. This was in a page I added tot he site pages gallery. When I added the code to my custom edit form the misbehaving method executed with no errors. From a practical perspective, it is moot, but from an understanding what went wrong perspective I am still trying to find an answer.

Comment: I am now unable to duplicate the error at all. It might have been fixed via an IIS reset or the gremlins moved on to something else. I am debating closing the question as "too localized".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){...}, "sp.js");

});
```

The document.ready() expects a function delegate where you cannot pass arguments directly.

Comment: I will give this a try. But like I mentioned above, the exact code worked in the CustomEditForm.aspx I created. This also would not really explain the error as the error states it is a problem in depScriptFileName not having a toLower() function.

Comment: Nope, did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Vardhaman, I'm going to select your answer. As I stated above. I cannot even reproduce the problem now...